# Is it possible to have LDK announce multiple IPv4 addresses?

Tags: lightning-development-kit

I'd like to be able to accept inbound connections on multiple addresses.

Comment: Could you give us more information about what you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have LDK announce your node with several network addresses.

Node announcements are broadcast by calling [`PeerManager::broadcast_node_announcement`](https://docs.rs/lightning/latest/lightning/ln/peer_handler/struct.PeerManager.html#method.broadcast_node_announcement), which simply takes an `addresses: Vec<NetAddress>`, allowing to announce multiple addresses.

The given [`NetAddress`](https://docs.rs/lightning/latest/lightning/ln/msgs/enum.NetAddress.html) might be an IPv4/IPv6 address, a hostname, or an onion service (V3) address.